# How to use replaceAll in Java to replace a chunk of code if a tag inside of them does not exist?

Tags: java, regex, xml, tags

I've been fighting with this `XML` document to replace a chunk of code if the tag `<properties>` doesn't appear there.

```
(<testsuite name)(?:(?!<properties>)[\s\S])*?(<\/testsuite>\r\n\t)|(<testsuite name)(?:(?!<properties>)[\s\S])*?(<\/testsuite>\r\n)
```

```
.replaceAll("(<testsuite name)(?:(?!<properties>)[\\s\\S])*?(<\\/testsuite>\\r\\n\\t)|(<testsuite name)(?:(?!<properties>)[\\s\\S])*?(<\\/testsuite>\\r\\n)"
```

Normally when checking this condition I am using the replace feature in `Notepad++` with the regular expression above, and it works. But it doesn't in `Java`.

To clarify, my goal is to delete the everything inside the `<testsuites>` tags whenever it doesn't contain `<properties>` tags.

My colleague said to add `*?` but I do not understand why.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" timestamp="2015-11-20T15:04:21.241Z" tests="10" failures="0" errors="0" time="1.24114">
      <testcase name="AssertTrue: System enclosure" classname="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" time="0"></testcase>
      <testcase name="AssertTrue: Operating system" classname="test.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" time="0"></testcase>
      <testcase name="AssertTrue: OS name exists. Actual: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;" classname="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" time="0"></testcase>
      <testcase name="AssertTrue: Network adapter" classname="test.xxxxx" time="0"></testcase>
      <testcase name="AssertTrue: Computer system" classname="test.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" time="0"></testcase>
      <testcase name="AssertTrue: Logical disks list" classname="xxxxxx" time="0"></testcase>
      <testcase name="AssertTrue: Export timestamp" classname="xxxxxx" time="0"></testcase>
      <testcase name="LogMessage: Global References: 284" classname="xxxxxx" time="0"></testcase>
      <testcase name="LogMessage: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)" classname="xxxxxx" time="0"></testcase>
      <testcase name="LogMessage: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx." classname="xxxxxx" time="0"></testcase>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</xml>
```

Comment: Try using `\r?\n` and omit the `\t`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply remove `\r?\n` from your regular expression, it matches the `<testsuite>` tag and its contents.

```js
const XML =
  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" timestamp="2015-11-20T15:04:21.241Z" tests="10" failures="0" errors="0" time="1.24114">
      <testcase name="AssertTrue: System enclosure" classname="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" time="0"></testcase>
      <testcase name="AssertTrue: Operating system" classname="test.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" time="0"></testcase>
      <testcase name="AssertTrue: OS name exists. Actual: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;" classname="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" time="0"></testcase>
      <testcase name="AssertTrue: Network adapter" classname="test.xxxxx" time="0"></testcase>
      <testcase name="AssertTrue: Computer system" classname="test.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" time="0"></testcase>
      <testcase name="AssertTrue: Logical disks list" classname="xxxxxx" time="0"></testcase>
      <testcase name="AssertTrue: Export timestamp" classname="xxxxxx" time="0"></testcase>
      <testcase name="LogMessage: Global References: 284" classname="xxxxxx" time="0"></testcase>
      <testcase name="LogMessage: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)" classname="xxxxxx" time="0"></testcase>
      <testcase name="LogMessage: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx." classname="xxxxxx" time="0"></testcase>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</xml>`;

const regExp = /(<testsuite name)(?:(?!<properties>)[\s\S])*?(<\/testsuite>\r\n\t)|(<testsuite name)(?:(?!<properties>)[\s\S])*?(<\/testsuite>)/;

console.log(XML.replace(regExp, ''));
```

Comment: I solved long time ago, but thanks for the solution provided!!!TOP!